# YUI Pure Grids Mangle Google Maps Controls

Tags: google-maps, yui-pure-css

I am using YUI Pure re-sizable grids. One of the elements needs to house a Google map. The map renders fine, markers and such are no problem; the Google Maps controls, on the other hand, are mangled beyond recognition. The buttons for zooming in and out are not visible. Have any of you solved this problem? The HTML in question looks as follows:

```
<div class="pure-g-r">
  <div class="pure-u-2-5">
    Some content.....
  </div>
  <div class="pure-u-3-5">
    <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the problem; thanks much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
#mapCanvas img {max-width: none; min-width: none;}
```